# How to SendKeys to input element that is created ad hoc when clicking in div element parent?

Tags: c#, html, selenium, exception

I am stuck in this problem: our webpage has a dynamic table that will load values (students' marks) on a `div` element. If we click on said `div`, a new child element `input` will be appended to the `div` and we should be able to input a new mark using `SendKeys` method. However, when I try to SendKeys, a `StaleElementReferenceException` appears.

Here is the element when the `input` is added (had to use a breakpoint as the element disappears as soon as the `div` element loses focus):

---

```
<tr>
    <td class="indice">1</td>
    <td id="accion-1-alumno-0" data-tooltip="" title="Bustos, Guido" class="has-tip titulo">Bustos, Guido</td>
    <td data-tooltip="" title="1º ESA" class="has-tip titulo">1º ESA</td>
    <td class="nota relative  media noeditable k-nivel2_tabla" style="text-align:center; color: #ed1c24!important">
        <div id="accion-1-celda-0-0-0" class="elemento comentarios">2,00</div>
    </td>
    <td class="nota relative " style="text-align:center; color: #ed1c24!important">
        <div id="accion-1-celda-1-0-0" class="elemento comentarios">
            <input id="editor" type="text" value="2" maxlength="7">
        </div>
    </td>
    <td class="nota relative " style="text-align:center; color: #000000!important">
        <div class="elemento comentarios">
            <span id="accion-1-editar-2-0" class="block left ellipsis span  comentario" title=""></span>
            <span id="accion-1-prismaticos-2-0" class="glyphicons glyph_observaciones observacion right"></span>
        </div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

---

And here is the code that I use to click on the `div` and try to `SendKeys`:

---

```
IWebElement inputNota = SeleniumHelper.FindByXPath("//td[text() = '"+ nombreAlumno +"']/following-sibling::td/div[contains(@id, 'accion-1-celda')]");

SeleniumHelper.Click(inputNota);

SeleniumHelper.SendKeys(inputNota.FindElement(By.Id("editor")), nota);
```

---

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a new element is appended to the html it means the DOM was refreshed, or at least the `<div>`, so the `driver` "lost" the previously located elements. You need to relocate it

```
string locator = "//td[text() = '"+ nombreAlumno +"']/following-sibling::td/div[contains(@id, 'accion-1-celda')]";

IWebElement inputNota = SeleniumHelper.FindByXPath(locator);

SeleniumHelper.Click(inputNota);

SeleniumHelper.SendKeys(SeleniumHelper.FindByXPath(locator).FindElement(By.Id("editor")), nota);
```

Comment: hi @Guy, I changed to search a second time for the locator, just as you suggested and the behaviour is as follows: selenium clicks the element correctly, however the input bow is not shown and NoSuchElement exception is shown. I tried adding a sleep just to make sure the input box would be shown, but it is not.

Comment: @elgato If the element was clicked correctly shouldn't the input filed appear? what it the value of `nombreAlumno` variable? maybe the click doesn't work (even if you didn't get any error).

Comment: the click happens because there is a red dot on the box when the element is clicked so I am sure the click is correct. I am also stump at why the box is not appearing. The value of nombreAlumno is "Bustos, Guido"

Comment: @elgato To clarify, are you trying to click on the element with id `accion-1-celda-0-0-0` or with id `accion-1-celda-1-0-0`?

Comment: well that was the problem. My xpath was:  
    string xpathNota = "//td[text() = '" + nombreAlumno + "']/following-sibling::td/div[contains(@id, 'accion-1-celda')]";  

Changing it to:  
string xpathNota = "//td[text() = '" + nombreAlumno + "']/following-sibling::td/div[contains(@id, 'accion-1-celda-1')]";  

Did the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @elgato You can also specify the index `following-sibling::td[2]/div[contains(@id, 'accion-1-celda')]`

Answer (score 0):

StaleElement occurs when the Element is removed/changed from the DOM. In any case you will need to regrab the element. A good way to do this is like so...

```
public static IWebElement HardFindElement(IWebDriver driver, By by)
    {
        IWebElement elementToReturn = null;

        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        wait.Until(drv =>
        {
            try
            {
                elementToReturn = driver.FindElement(by);
                return true;
            }
            catch
            {

                return false;
            }
        });

        return elementToReturn;
    }
```

This will wait up to 30 seconds until it is able to regrab the element from the DOM. You will want to do this after the click to reinitialize the element accordingly

Comment: Okay now somewhere you studied and have written this answer, eh? That's really great. So don't be too hurry to call someone childish or something like that. I was really trying to help you. And I want to tell you that element removed from the DOM is not exactly stale element, when the reference to the element is lost that becomes stale element.

Comment: @Rajagopalan my original answer was still correct but in the sense of using a Page Object Pattern based framework, which i'm made to believe this isn't. Therefore I tailored a solution that uses FindsBy attribute instead (since this question doesn't include the use of PageFactory). In any case when an element is removed from DOM, the reference is aswell. There are ways selenium can still re-attain that reference if using Page Object Pattern. In this case it would be easier to regrab the element instead of rearchitecting the whole framework to use Page Object Pattern.

Comment: The answer you have stated clearly that he has to wait until element becomes visible, not only your answer, your code perfectly did that Job. So it was pretty clearly to me you have mistaken stale element. But it's okay if you are not ready to admit! Let's move on! Once again you are wrong with your understanding, element need not to be removed from the DOM when element goes to stale. Your understanding is still wrong.

Comment: @Rajagopalan I understand the element needs to simply change in the DOM to be stale, not be removed. But to be changed in the DOM in an angular application it typically is removed and re-added to the DOM accordingly (re-cached with new data). I realised it wasn't specified whether or not this was an angular application which I had assume. Which I admit is where my misunderstanding arose from.

Comment: hi @Taran, the driver is already wrapped in a helper that takes into account waiting for the element to appear and indeed I am using a POM structure, so the problem is not quite that but thank you for your time